# Error 1064 SQL en query

Tags: mysql, sql

No puedo ver el error de esta sentencia

```
create table authority (
id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) 
primary key, name varchar(50));
```

Comment: Siempre que hagas una pregunta procura dar detalles como en este caso con que herramienta estas trabajando y cual es el resultado que esperas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la sintaxis correcta en MySQL es:

```
create table authority (
    id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: no lo puse en el post. Se trata de una MYSQL. Y sigue sin hacer la query de manera correcta. Meda el  mismo codigo de error

Comment: Editado para MySQL

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, funciono !!!